# FCM Payload null in Laravel production API

Tags: php, android, laravel, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Laravel API that dispatch push notifications using laravel-push-notifications  framework through FCM. In my localhost, I receive message with data payload but in production mode the same code returns payload null when receive message.

This is method in Laravel to send push notifications:

```
public static function sendPushNotification($deviceToken, $actionId, $text) {
    $deviceToken = (string) $deviceToken;

    try {
        $message = \PushNotification::Message($text, array(
                    'badge' => 1,
                    'sound' => 'default',
                    'content-available' => 1,
                    'custom' => array(
                        'registerID' => 'teste',
                        'fromAPI' => true,
                        'action' => $actionId
                    ),
                    'payload' => array(
                        'notification' => array(
                            'action' => $actionId,
                            'title' => $text
                        ),
                    ),
        ));


        if (strlen($deviceToken) > 64) {
            $returnAndroid = \PushNotification::app('appJurAndroid')
                    ->to($deviceToken)
                    ->send($message);
        } else {
            $returnIos = \PushNotification::app('appJurIOS')
                    ->to($deviceToken)
                    ->send($message);
        }

    } catch (AdapterException $e) {
        Log::error("Push notification failure: {$e->getMessage()}");
    }
}
```

In my Android App, when the FCM delegate method is called:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
```

The remoteMessage.getData() or remoteMessage.getNotification() is null.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `custom` and `payload` part with `data` and `notification`.

Currently, your payload would look like this:

```
{
    'badge': 1,
    'sound': 'default',
    'content-available': 1,
    'custom' : {
        'registerID': 'teste',
        'fromAPI': true,
        'action': $actionId
     },
     'payload': {
         'notification': {
             'action': $actionId,
             'title': $text
          }
     }
}
```

It ***should*** be:

```
{
    'badge': 1,
    'sound': 'default',
    'content_available': true,
    'data' : {
        'registerID': 'teste',
        'fromAPI': true,
        'action': $actionId
     },
     'notification': {
             'action': $actionId,
             'title': $text
     }
}
```

Also notice that I replaced `content-available` to `content_available`, which is the correct format. With that said, AFAIK, `content_available` is only used for payloads sent to iOS clients.

See [Message Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) and the [FCM HTTP Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) for a guide in the parameters.